# Julia mmap: Fast(er) way of reading columnwise?

Tags: arrays, julia, memory-mapping

Disclaimer: I'm new to both Julia and memory mapping.

I'm mapping large files (~80Gb) consisting of recordings from ~400 channels using Mmap.mmap. Since the values are saved in channel order 1 timepoint at a time the obvious way to shape the memory map is (n channels, n timepoints). However, reading an entire channel from this map requires reading a single row and 100000000+ columns. I only have to do this for one channel but reading in this way is **way** slower compared to if I could read rowwise.

Structure of current memory map:

```
ch1: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...
ch2: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...
ch3: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...
ch4: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...
.
.
.
```

I have gotten similar performance from the following:

Reading each value in for loops:

```
ch = channels to read from
len = Time window (tmin:tmax)
res::Matrix{Int16} = Matrix{Int16}(undef, length(len), length(ch))

for (nch, c) in enumerate(ch)
        for (ntim, t) in enumerate(len)
            res[ntim, nch] = memorymap[c, t]
        end
    end
```

Using slicing:

```
ch = channels to read from
len = Time window (tmin:tmax)
res::Union{Matrix{Int16}, Vector{Int16}} = memorymap[ch, len]
```

Both methods are inside a function whose other parts are creating the memory map(using another function) and checking so the channels to read from and tmin/tmax exists. I will probably try multithreading but a more efficient method would be good/better.

EDIT: Switched place of rowwise/columnwise. Reading rowwise is obviously faster.

Comment: this is using the wrong file format for the job, try to convert data into Arrow/Feather file (e.g. with Arrow.jl)

Comment: one of the main problem is when you `mmap` a file, you're operating on a vector of bytes, which doesn't align with your "columns" unless each number has the same number of raw string characters